# delete method delete all the values in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

What i want to do is i want to delete only item that is been clicked

todoList Component:

template :

```
<ul class="list-group">
                  <todo v-for="(todo,i) in todo" :key="i" :todoString="todo.todoString" :completed="todo.completed"
                  @on-delete="del(todo)" />
              </ul>
```

script :

```
 data() {
    return {
      todo: [
        { todoString: "make videos Angular", completed: true },
        { todoString: "make videos React", completed: false },
        { todoString: "make videos Vue", completed: true },
        { todoString: "make videos Javascript", completed: false },
      ],
    };
  },
 
 del(deltodo) {
          this.todo = this.todo.filter(todos => {
            todos.todoString !== deltodo.todoString;
           console.log(this.todo.length)
          });
          console.log(this.todo.length)
        },
```

TodoComponent :

template:

```
<li class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item">
    <button class="btn border-0 text-left flex-grow-1">{{todoString}}</button>
    <form action="" class="flex-grow-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </form>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</button>
    <button  key="" @click="$emit('on-delete')" class="btn btn-outline-danger">delete</button>

</li>
```

script :

```
props:{
    todoString:String,
    completed:Boolean
},
```

the problem is when i delete one item it deletes the all item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by passing the index to `del` rather than the entire object:

```
@on-delete="del(i)"
```

Then the `del` would be implemented using `splice`:

```
del(i) {
  // remove 1 element at index i
  this.todo.splice(i, 1);
}
```

If you want to use `filter`, you need to return from the callback:

```
this.todo = this.todo.filter(todos => {
  return todos.todoString !== deltodo.todoString
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In v-for you've named the single element the same as your array which might be the problem.
Try this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
                  <todo v-for="(t,i) in todo" :key="i" :todoString="t.todoString" :completed="t.completed"
                  @on-delete="del(t)" />
              </ul>
```

There is also a problem in your filter function, you're not returning anything. This should work:

```
 del(deltodo) {
          this.todo = this.todo.filter(todos => {
            console.log(this.todo.length);
            return todos.todoString !== deltodo.todoString;
          });
          console.log(this.todo.length)
        },
```